# How to create laravel custom storage:link?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-5.6

How to create laravel custom storage:link?

I would like to point 
`project/public/storage`   >> `project/storage/app/tenancy/tenants`

Comment: Please answer this question.

Comment: Do you mean create the folders within the storage link?aaaaaa Once you run `php artisan storage:link` you are then able to link to where you would like within the storage folder.

Comment: I means that `php artisan storage:link` is default path `project/public/storage  >> project/storage/app/public` , but i want to path `project/public/storage  >> project/storage/app/tenancy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment it is not possible to customize the path with this command. I looked at the source code and couldn't find any hints regarding to this issue.

The simplest thing you can do is make the symbolic link yourself.
The only thing this command does is create that symlink with PHP. This is the source code:

```
if (! windows_os()) {
    return symlink($target, $link);
}

$mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';

exec("mklink /{$mode} \"{$link}\" \"{$target}\"");
```

If you really need to make a command for it. You can create your own. If you want to see how Taylor did it, you can look in the following file:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php`

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

In `config/filesystems.php` :

```
'links' => [
    public_path() . '_html\storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

after following this tutorial to change /public to /public_html

https://developerhowto.com/2018/11/12/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder/

Comment: This wasn't available at the time of answering. But now it is. Can you add the Laravel version that introduced this to your answer?